# Hide discount infos without canceling the coupon in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using a coupon for a calculation in the Woocommerce cart. It automatically adds a discount to the total so the right amount can be sent to payments gateways.

I'd like to hide all infos about this coupons/discount from visitors.

**Problem**: The only method I've found (see below) hides the coupon field, row (from totals) and messages, but also disable the coupon...

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_coupons_enabled', 'hide_coupon_field' );
function hide_coupon_field( $enabled ) {
    if ( is_cart() || is_checkout() ) {
        $enabled = false;
    }
    return $enabled;
}
```

Is there a hook allowing to hide everything related to the discount without canceling the coupon?

---

**EDIT:** 
Looks like it's impossible to simply remove the discount line in the **order-details**. So a simple solution, inspired by helgatheviking suggestion, might be to remove all the totals generated by this part

```
<?php if ( $totals = $order->get_order_item_totals() ) foreach ( $totals as $total ) : ?>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row"><?php echo $total['label']; ?></th>
                <td><?php echo $total['value']; ?></td>
            </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

And then to echo them one by one the way I need it. I'm already able to show the order total with this

```
<td><?php echo number_format($order->get_total(),2,'.','')."&#8364;"; ?></td>
```

but now I'm trying to retrieve the **order subtotal**, and this code

```
<td><?php echo number_format($order->get_item_subtotal(),2,'.','')."&#8364;"; ?></td>
```

gives me a Warning: Missing argument 1 for WC_Order::get_item_subtotal().

I'm not sure if `get_item_subtotal()` is the right way to get the order subtotal. And if so, what argument is missing? Or should I search around `get_line_subtotal` or `get_subtotal_to_display`?

Comment: If you look at the `get_item_subtotal()` method in the `WC_Order` class you will see that an `$item` argument is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there does not seem to be as there is no filter in the `get_coupons()` method of the cart class. If you went to the WooCommerce git repo and sent a pull request with a filter here and an explanation as to why it should be there, they might consider merging it in. I've done that a few times.

You could also, copy the `checkout/review-order.php` and `cart/cart-totals.php` templates into your theme and remove the following two blocks of code:

```
<?php foreach ( WC()->cart->get_coupons( 'cart' ) as $code => $coupon ) : ?>
                <tr class="cart-discount coupon-<?php echo esc_attr( $code ); ?>">
                    <th><?php wc_cart_totals_coupon_label( $coupon ); ?></th>
                    <td><?php wc_cart_totals_coupon_html( $coupon ); ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
```

and

```
<?php foreach ( WC()->cart->get_coupons( 'order' ) as $code => $coupon ) : ?>
    <tr class="order-discount coupon-<?php echo esc_attr( $code ); ?>">
        <th><?php wc_cart_totals_coupon_label( $coupon ); ?></th>
        <td><?php wc_cart_totals_coupon_html( $coupon ); ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Keep in mind that this prevents the display of ALL coupon discounts and will end up looking like the following screenshots:

[image: Hide coupons in Cart]
[image: Hide coupons in Checkout]

I'm not a fan of overriding the more complex WC templates... especially not the ones pertaining to the checkout process. I've had to fix many sites that stopped working when their theme template overrides became obsolete as WooCommerce develops.

**Edit**

I tracked down the Discount row in the `order/order-details.php` template. It is from the function `$order->get_order_item_totals()`... this returns an array of rows and can be filtered. So, this removes the row from the order received page:

```
function so_25714509_get_order_item_totals( $total_rows ){
    unset( $total_rows['order_discount'] );
    return $total_rows;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_order_item_totals', 'so_25714509_get_order_item_totals' );
```

Comment: Thank you, I was doing this before but couldn't get rid of the discount line in order-details (the page after proceeding to checkout). I thought there was a simpler solution but I think your way is the easiest way. 
I removed the part responsible for displaying all the totals `<?php if ( $totals = $order->get_order_item_totals() ) foreach ( $totals as $total ) : ?>
   <tr>
    <th scope="row"><?php echo $total['label']; ?></th>
    <td><?php echo $total['value']; ?></td>
   </tr>
 <?php endforeach; ?>`

Comment: And now I'm trying to display each line calling it when I need it. I'm only stuck with echoing the subtotal on the template... Could you help me with this please?

Comment: I'm trying to show it with `<?php echo number_format($order->get_item_subtotal(),2,'.','')."&#8364;"; ?>` but I have an error... What should I replace this `get_item_subtotal()` with?

Comment: I'm not really following you. Why do you need to replace the subtotal? And what should it be instead? Can you edit your question to reflect this?

Comment: I don't want to replace `get_item_subtotal()`, I just want to be able to show the order subtotal and now I'm getting a warning. I just edited the question, I hope it's more clear.

Comment: I've edited my answer and think it now hides the coupon discount info on `checkout/order-details.php`. Do you need need to adjust the subtotals? They should've been shown by default.

Comment: Well, apparently the order-details.php is the page two steps after validating the cart (first you validate, then you chose a payment method and submit). Can you try it please? If I'm right, you will see the details of your order and the discount will still appear. That's the page I'm struggling with (sorry if it wasn't clear). And thanks for taking the time, I appreciate.

Comment: Great, it's working except for a tiny detail, `['order_discount']` has to be changed to `['cart_discount']` and the line vanishes! Thanks again for you help, you saved my day! :)

Comment: Cool! I guess it depends on the type of discount? Because there can also be an 'order_discount' row and that's what I was seeing in my tests. You can see the full `get_order_item_totals()` method in the Order class.

Comment: please check this question also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49505056/woocommerce-create-new-discount-functionality